# MySQL server started as a slave

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

can I use MySQL server when it is started as slave for replication? can i update and delete rows on databases?

Comment: Only if the relationship is circular and the master is also slaved to this slave.  Or you can modify it, but your data will become inconsistent against the master, which is the whole intent of replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can update, delete, alter table and many other things. But your changes does not sync back if your replication is not master-master.